# In OS X is it possible to get the text of a dock icon's badge label with applescript?

Tags: macos, icons, applescript, badge, dock

OS X dock icon badge labels display numbers (only?). Is it possible to get the number of a specific badge label with applescript?
e.g. the count of "Unread Messages" on the Skype dock icon?

Any help would be appreciated
Alex

Comment: No it isn't, unless the application has an AppleScript dictionary containing an appropriate property or command

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I learned that it can be done for some apps with shell.
As an example here with the app store:
'set my_var to do shell script "
defaults read -app \"/Applications/App Store.app\" appStoreBadgeCount;
"'
But it only works if the value is in the app preferences (which is the case for the app store but unfortunately not for skype).